# Is there any common research model for supersonic transport?

Tags: aerodynamics, supersonic

Is there any common research platform, like the [Common Research Model](https://commonresearchmodel.larc.nasa.gov/) of NASA for supersonic transport flight?

I assume that in aerospace industry, every company has his own research platforms depending on previous projects but was there any common model that companies shared for this purpose?

Comment: Does any major company even research supersonic transports?

Comment: Of-course they do, if it's not always internal they just outsource it to research centers (NASA, ONERA, DLR etc.), or universities. http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/airbus-patents-supersonic-plane-that-could-hit-mach-4-5-1.3178955

Comment: What about this: https://lbpw.larc.nasa.gov/sbpw2/propagation/lm1021/?

Comment: @MarkJonesJr. Great! That's indeed an answer to the question, the CRM was also studied for the other workshops (high-lift etc.) so we could consider this one a common research supersonic platform at the moment.

Comment: @MarkJonesJr. You could update your answer, for me to accept it.

Comment: @AlexandrosK. done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to NASA [here](https://lbpw.larc.nasa.gov/sbpw2/propagation/lm1021/):

> This test case is an aircraft concept previously used as an optional
>   case (LM1021) in the 1st Sonic Boom Prediction Workshop. This
>   configuration is described in the following reference: John
>   Morgenstern, Nicole Norstrud, Jack Sokhey, Steve Martins, and Juan J.
>   Alonso, “Advanced Concept Studies for Supersonic Commercial Transports
>   Entering Service in the 2018 to 2020 Period,” NASA
>   CR-2013-217820,DOI:2060/20130010174. See NTRS Record. There is also a
>   description in the following reference: John M. Morgenstern, Michael
>   Buonanno, and Frank Marconi, “Full Configuration Low Boom Model and
>   Grids for 2014 Sonic Boom Prediction Workshop,” AIAA-2013-647.

Comment: Interesting but I am asking for a common research model, i.e. a model that was shared between other aerospace research centers throughout the world, like ONERA, DLR etc.

Comment: @AlexandrosK. I thought as much but couldn't find something equivalent.